# Implications of the impossibility of efficient sampling from random non-Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, proof-complexity

Nisan's answer to this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/562/how-to-produce-a-random-graph-that-does-not-have-a-hamiltonian-cycle/567#567) shows the Impossiblity of efficient sampling from random non-Hamiltonian graphs (unless $NP=coNP$). I am interested in the implications of this conjecture.

> Does the Impossibility of efficient sampling from random non-Hamiltonian graphs imply that $NP \ne coNP$?

I am also interested in other complexity implications.

EDIT July 4: My intuition is that efficient sampling from random non-Hamiltonian graphs is possible if and only if $NP=coNP$. It hints a probabilistic characterization of class $NP$ (possibly connected to PCP theorem).

I would be very interested in published works about (preferably efficient) sampling from random non-Hamiltonian graphs (and any possible connection to PCP theorem).

Comment: Cross-posted to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173365

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Please post your answer from MathOverflow for completeness.